# One word meaning "good wish" or "well wishing thought"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any one word in English that means a "good wish" or "well wishing thought"?

For example, "It's a good wish/well wishing thought, and I hope it comes true."

Comment: Perhaps 'aspiration' :a hope or ambition of achieving something!

Comment: Nothing specific I am familiar with, but you can say "nice dream" instead of "good thought" depending what you specifically want to convey. There's also "prayer" in certain (more religious) circumstances. Why do you need a single word? Why won't "nice thought" work?

Comment: Certainly. 'Benediction'; 'benison'. So let's forget those (though 'blessing/s' may sometimes work) and go with 'best wishes' or 'kind wish'.

Answer (score 2):

felicitation, or felicitations
usually plural

> 1.The act of expressing joy or acknowledgment, as for the achievement or good fortune of another.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/felicitation)
>
> Felicitations
>  Words expressing praise for an achievement or good
>   wishes on a special occasion. ‘it is my honour to extend the
>   felicitations of the president of France to you’
>  [Oxford Living
>   Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/felicitations)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **'well-meaning'**, **'well-wished'** or **'well-intentioned'**.

"That's a well-meaning thought, and I hope it comes true."

Answer (score 0):

How about **goodwill**?

Merriam-Webster [defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goodwill)

> kindly feeling of approval and support : benevolent interest or concern
>
> > people of goodwill

Answer (score -2):

Godspeed is nice, especially if the person you're talking to is about to begin a journey.

Comment: Yes but godspeed is not a noun, which is what the questioner seeks.

Comment: Some dictionaries say it’s also a noun.